# Blender Internal Bake Wireframe

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, wireframe

I am trying to bake a texture for a mesh, a simple diffuse material with the wireframe on top of it. I'm trying to get the effect you can see here: https://youtu.be/7dK1VVtja5c?t=9s.

I need to bake the entire texture for use in Unity. I tried Cycles+Freestyle, it works well, but Freestyle can't be baked as far as I know. I tried the wireframe modifier, but that means having a much more complex mesh, if the surface is flat I want a flat mesh there.

So I came back to Blender Internal, since I don't need any fancy light effect anyway. The wireframe material works great, but I couldn't find a way to bake it on top of the diffuse material...

Any idea?

Comment: If you have freestyle done, you can [export it to .svg](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/export_svg.html?highlight=freestyle) format and then [import svg](https://code.google.com/p/vectex/wiki/Documentation) back in blender (Note that not every svg imports correctly, so it may not work).

Answer (score 2):

You just can go into the UV editor and choose Export UV layout. This is a good texture for wireframe Objects. Just combine it with your diffuse map (Gimp) and you have your wireframe Texture.